# Why does the Command + delete not work in Neovim?

Tags: neovim

In Vim, you can use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete all texts before the current cursor on the line (on insert-mode).

However, this functionality doesn't seem to exist in Neovim. I tried moving my `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` to somewhere else temporarily but only found it is persistent.

Why does this useful key combination not work in Neovim? Or is it only me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cmd + Delete` is (obviously) a macOS only shortcut. I may be wrong but I think Neovim removed the runtime files that provided OS specific shortcuts. Anyway you can achieve the same using the standard `Ctrl + U`. I say standard because you can try this shortcut on most Unix terminal applications (try it directly in Bash!) and it does the same regardless of the operating system (that means `Ctrl + U` does the same in macOS, any Linux distribution, FreeBSD, Windows Subsystem for Linux, etc.)

Vim and of course Neovim make heavy use of standard terminal shortcuts, for example you can suspend them and go back to your command line with `Ctrl + Z`, or delete the word before the cursor with `Ctrl + W`. `:h CTRL-` and then `Tab` will allow you to see all the shortcuts with the `Ctrl` modifier.

Comment: Thanks. Am I the only one who sees the `Ctrl + u` on Terminal delete all the characters on the line, not only the characters before the current cursor? I use Zsh, though.

Comment: I haven't use Zsh before but this seems to be the problem and solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483604/which-shortcut-in-zsh-does-the-same-as-ctrl-u-in-bash